# sails v10.0 on mysql encountering 'schema' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

i'm trying out sails js version 0.10.0 with sails-mysql adapter 0.10.6

I created two models:

***Customer.js***

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'someMysqlServer',

  attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    store: {
        model: 'Store'
    }
  }
};
```

and ***Store.js***

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'someMysqlServer',

  attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    customers: {
        model: 'Customer',
        required: false
    }
  }
};
```

when I first run the application, all is fine and I can see that it created two tables on my database. However, when I try to restart the application I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined
    at __FIND__ (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails-mys
ql\lib\adapter.js:808:42)
    at afterwards (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails-m
ysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:86:5)
    at C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\con
nections\spawn.js:40:7
    at Ping._callback (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sai
ls-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:81:7)
    at Ping.Sequence.end (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\
sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:78:24)
    at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_mod
ules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:87:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modu
les\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:213:24)
    at Parser.write (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails
-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sai
ls-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules
\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:75:28)
```

and if I drop the tables and restart the application, it'll be able to run and re-create the table, but won't go further, when I get to this controller.

```
module.exports = {
    add: function(req, res){
        var store = {
            name: 'strore2'
        }
        Store.create(store).exec(function(err, result){
            Customer.create({name: 'customer1', store: result.id}).exec(function (err1, result1){
                return res.json({created: result1, error: err1});   
            });
        });

    }

};
```

and will throw this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined
    at __CREATE__ (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails-m
ysql\lib\adapter.js:386:42)
    at afterwards (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails-m
ysql\lib\connections\spawn.js:86:5)
    at C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails-mysql\lib\con
nections\spawn.js:40:7
    at Ping._callback (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sai
ls-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:81:7)
    at Ping.Sequence.end (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\
sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:78:24)
    at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_mod
ules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:87:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modu
les\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:213:24)
    at Parser.write (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sails
-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules\sai
ls-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\fray\NodeJs\testingsails10_2\test1001\node_modules
\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:75:28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a broken dependencies issue.  Try:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear
npm install
```

To reinstall all the dependencies, then try `sails lift`.

At this point you will have Sails installed locally in your project, and `sails lift` will use that copy.  To perform a similar surgery on your global sails install, do:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g sails
npm cache clear
sudo npm install -g sails
```

Then `rm -rf node_modules/sails` in your project so that `sails lift` will use the global install.