# Sails Upgrade v10.5 Waterline "Migrate - safe" option gives errors?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

When I upgraded Sails from V0.9 to V0.10 I ran into trouble with Waterline. I have exhausted my options as far as finding the solution online. The problem is:

Sails v0.10 ask for the migrate property to be set and I do set it inside my models.js config file - migrate:"safe".

My server console keeps giving me the following error:

```
node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/validations.js:77
Object.keys(attrs[attr]).forEach(function(prop) {
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
```

Did anybody else run into this problem?

Comment: It's probably a dependencies issue; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558153/sails-v10-0-on-mysql-encountering-schema-of-undefined/25572465#25572465

Comment: I tried clearing cache and removing existing modules with no luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I realized after a bit that I had earlier added the following to my models. After removing it, I was able to run sails lift with no problems. Maybe check your models to ensure that everything is kosher.

```js
autoCreatedAt: true,
autoUpdatedAt: true
```